# How to convert string “2.000,65” into decimal 2,000.65 (en-Us) culture in c#

Tags: c#, globalization, culture, decimalformat, invariantculture

I have string value of "2.000,65" in German (de-DE) culture format. I want to convert this value into decimal and that too also in English (ed-US) format in c#, like "2,000.65".

Summary:-

I have a string value : "2.000,65"

Now wanted to convert this value into decimal en-US (US English) format as : 2,000.65 in c#

Hope, now its clear to understand question.

I have tried various option, but not able to achieve it.

Can you please help me out ?

Thanks.

Herin

Comment: show what you tried. decimals don't have a format, their string representations do

Comment: This is so easy language to understand question...!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
decimal money = decimal.Parse("2.000,65", new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
string result = money.ToString("N2", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

If you want to show the dollar sign you can use [`"C"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#CFormatString) instead of [`"N2"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#NFormatString).

Comment: Hi Tim, it looks good, but the value after decimal point is not coming in english (en-US) culture after converting from de-DE. So here in ed-US format it showing 2,000 instead of 2,000.65. What to do to get decimal value also ?

Comment: What is "ed-US"? Have you tried my code? It works as expected.

Comment: Sorry, not ed-US, its en-US. And I have tried your code, its working, but the value of after decimal places is not coming. So here in my case it showing value 2000.00 instead of 2,000.65.

Comment: @Herin: i still don't understand. My code works as expected with the value `"2.000,65"` the result is `"2,000.65"`. So what code are you using or where are you outputting the value? Maybe it's just a display issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
string stringValue = "2.000,65";
var decimalValue = decimal.Parse(stringValue, new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
var decimnalUsValue = decimalValue.ToString("N2", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```